# Error estimation for $f(x)=\sin \sqrt{x}$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Let $f(x)=\sin \sqrt{x}$, then $f'(x)=\frac1{2\sqrt{x}}\cos \sqrt{x}$ and $f''(x)=-\frac1{4x\sqrt{x}}\cos \sqrt{x}-\frac1{4x}\sin \sqrt x$.

Thus the Taylor polynomial of degree 2 at $x=\frac{\pi^2}9$ is $P(x)=\frac{\sqrt 3}2+\frac3{4\pi}(x-\frac{\pi^2}9)-\frac{27+9\sqrt 3\pi}{16\pi^3}(x-\frac{\pi^2}9)^2$.

I want approximate $\left | f(x)-P(x) \right |$ where $x\in \left [ 1,\frac{10}9 \right ]$ with error less than $\frac1{5000}$.

I know that the remainder is less than $\max \left \{ \left | \frac{f'''(t)}{3!} : t\in \left [ 1,x \right ] \right | \right \}\cdot \left | \left ( x-\frac{\pi^2}{9} \right )^3 \right |$, but I can't estimate this value. Please help me. ( Use $\pi^2=9.8696$ )

Comment: Are you saying you cannot find the 3rd derivative and then evlaute what its max value is over that range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that for $t\in [1,10/9]$ we have
$$\begin{align}
|f'''(t)| &=\left|\frac{3}{8}t^{-5/2}\cos\sqrt{t}+\frac{1}{8}t^{-2}\sin\sqrt{t}+\frac{1}{4}t^{-2}\sin\sqrt{t}+\frac{1}{8}t^{-3/2}\cos\sqrt{t}\right|\\
&= \frac{3}{8}t^{-5/2}\cos\sqrt{t}+\frac{1}{8}t^{-2}\sin\sqrt{t}+\frac{1}{4}t^{-2}\sin\sqrt{t}+\frac{1}{8}t^{-3/2}\cos\sqrt{t}\\
&\le \frac{3}{8}\cos1+\frac{1}{8}\sin\sqrt{\frac{10}{9}}+\frac{1}{4}\sin\sqrt{\frac{10}{9}}+\frac{1}{8}\cos1\approx .596<\frac{6}{10}\\
\end{align}$$
since on this interval $\cos\sqrt{t}$ and negative powers of $t$ are positive and decreasing while $\sin\sqrt{t}$ is positive and increasing, and that
$$\left|\left(x-\frac{\pi^2}{9}\right)^3\right|=\left|x-\frac{\pi^2}{9}\right|^3\le \left(\frac{\pi^2}{9}-1\right)^3\approx .0009<\frac{1}{1000}$$
thus the error is less than $\frac{1}{10000}$.

Remark: You can get a rougher estimate (which is still better than $\frac{1}{5000}$) using the fact that $\sin\sqrt{t},\cos\sqrt{t}\le 1$ rather than estimating them more explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I have
$$\sin \left({{\sqrt{2}\,\sqrt{19}}\over{6}}\right)+{{3\,\cos \left(
 {{\sqrt{2}\,\sqrt{19}}\over{6}}\right)\,\sqrt{2}\,\sqrt{19}\,\left(x
 -{{19}\over{18}}\right)}\over{38}}-{{\left(27\,\cos \left({{\sqrt{2}
 \,\sqrt{19}}\over{6}}\right)\,\sqrt{2}\,\sqrt{19}+171\,\sin \left({{
 \sqrt{2}\,\sqrt{19}}\over{6}}\right)\right)\,\left(x-{{19}\over{18}}
 \right)^2}\over{1444}}$$
obtained by taylor series at $x=19/18$ with error $\approx 10^{-5}$